Is there such a thing as a purely personal explanation? Is god a purely personal explanation?
The answer to why I cooked food can be explained either through the natural/mechanistic processes of cooking or because “I wanted to” as a personal explanation.
But my wants are also supposedly mechanistic or determined or rooted in naturalistic processes that underlie these desires. As such, is a personal explanation really ever an explanation at all?
Without the natural, physical processes underlying personal desires, can purely personal explanations ever explain anything? Since god does not have these processes and is completely immaterial, can He be a good explanation?

it's called "god of the gaps" concept. If I can't explains something, then it's god

Some gods are purely immaterial, some are not. The question needs a sufficiently concise definition about which god it is, and even "Abrahamic god" is not enough because there is no consensus about even those gods. Not even biblical god is sufficient. You need the specific cult. All those versions of gods should get society security numbers or something to tell them apart.


Is a personal explanation really ever an explanation at all?
Explanation of the type “because I wanted to do …” are called
teleological explanations (telos = goal). Humans have goals and try
to reach their goals. The action of humans and of animals of similar
species are best understood when considered goal oriented.

Can God
be a good explanation?
The conception of God follows an anthropomorphic model: The
believers ascribe God personal traits and intentions like a human has.
They attempt to understand events by assuming that these events are
intentionally caused by God.
The problem with this kind of
personal explanation: Due to ignorance it is often an ad-hoc explanation. The
real mechanism behind the event remains unexplained.
In addition the god-concept is a problematic concept itself: History shows the ongoing debate about the existence of God since thousands of years. It is better to refer to established causes as explanations or to mark a question as open and in need of further research.




Is there such a thing as a purely personal explanation?

Rushi says:

Every explanation I make is personal and interpersonal. That I make it means I value making it — so personal. That I'm speaking (writing, communicating, 'languaging') means it's interpersonal. EVEN IF ITS ENTIRELY IN MY OWN HEAD. I'm still using a not-my-own-invented language. And that makes me subconsciously subject to frames not of my choosing, as Sapir-Whorf adumbrated.

To which, in response to your 1st paragraph, may be added the comment of g s (written to another question).

Mechanistic and teleological "why" have almost nothing to do with each other. In the ancient days of superstition, priests answered "why did the chicken cross the road" by claiming that it wanted to get to the other side. Now thanks to science we know better: why did the chicken cross the road? Because it put one foot in front of the other.

Which reminds me that a certain old chap had talked about this in more detail a few years ago.

In philosophy the word "explanation" is ambiguous when referring to actions. It can refer to the motivation of the agent, or the causation of the agent in terms of the workings of the mind. Even in dualistic worldviews, the mind follows some causation explaining thinking mistakes and miscalculations.
So when any actor demonstrates an action, it is possible to ask:

How does the agenda defend their action to others?
How does this agent consciously defend their motivation to themselves ?
What is the subconscious (real) motivation?
What are the preceding causes in those motivations?
How does the agents mind work to produce this actions intention?
How does the agents body work to execute their intention?
How does the agents mind perceive physical reality?
How does the agents mind influence physical reality?
What stuff if the agents mind made off, and how does that stuff work to make the mind work?
Why does the mind of this agent work differently from that of other agents?

Even for human agents, several of those questions are not usually answerable in complete and uncontroversial ways.
Imagine a horrible criminal prosecuted in court, like Ted Bundy, where we can see how all the answers to the question above about motive are different. And consider the Mind-Body problem of philosophy for the other half of questions. And so the word "explanation" is ambiguous as to which of those questions it refers to.
This does not become any easier when talking about speculative agents like ghosts, spirits, fairies, angels, demons, gods, devils, ...
Typically humans will just try to imagine a human mind with invisible body for those entities, though religions do not necessarily support such views (though religions are happy to tolerate whatever it takes to keep a gullible believer within the cult). But the mind of such entities remains elusive, proof of their existence sketchy at best, and their motivations hidden behind a veil of "gods work in mysterious ways".
As such their explanatory power is low, and the typical use of gods in social care is to provide solace, not philosophically sound explanations that can be judged to be true or false.
